# breaking a list into a new list of 2 neighboring elements

Tags: list, ocaml

I need to break a list like `[1;2;3;4;5]` into `[[1;2]; [3;4]; [5]]` in OCaml.

I wrote the following function but it is giving me an error (Error: This expression has type 'a list but an expression was expected of type 'a                                                                         The type variable 'a occurs inside 'a list)

```
let rec getNewList l =
    match l with 
    [] -> failwith "empty list"
    | [x] -> [x]
    | x::(y::_ as t) -> [x;y] :: getNewList t;;
```

What am I missing? how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You want a function of type `'a list -> 'a list list`. However, the second branch of your match returns something of type `'a list`.

As a side comment, you shouldn't consider it an error if the input is an empty list. There's a perfectly natural answer for this case. Otherwise you'll have a lot of extra trouble writing your function.

Answer (score 1):

You're not far from a solution. Three things :

- if the list is empty, you definitely want your result to be the empty list
- second case should be `[x] -> [[x]]`
- for the main case, how many times should `y` appear in your result ?